# Regex to find only letters using PHP

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to create a regex which will detect if a string has only letters in it. Can anyone tell me if the following code does that correctly?

```
$text = "asdsad";
if (ereg('[^A-Za-z]', $text)) {
  echo "More then letters";
}

else {
  echo "only letters";    
}
```

Comment: What is your question? I don't understand your first sentence.

Comment: Russell, consider that the person may not have English as their first language.

Comment: @Steve: It's perfectly acceptable to state that you do not understand the *only* sentence in the question...

Comment: @Russell true, but when others are managing to give answers, obviously the question CAN be understood.  So if we as a community are going to help people we need to be considerate of those who are learning English, just as we might be considerate of those learning (say) PHP.

Answer (score 14):

[The condition evaluates to true](http://codepad.org/xl8F0rAI), if that is what you meant.

You want to make sure a string has letters only?

Try this...

```
if (preg_match('/^\pL+$/u', $text)) {
   echo "Letters only";
} else {
   echo "More than letters";
}
```

[See it on ideone](http://ideone.com/8l20J).

So you can understand a few things...

- [`ereg()` has been deprecated as of PHP 5.3](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ereg.php). Stop using it, and use `preg_match()`.
- When using a regex with `preg_match()`, you need to specify a regex delimiter. Most regex flavours use `/`, but PHP lets you use most matching pair of chars, e.g. `~`
- You are missing start and end anchors. This means you won't be matching the string from start to finish
- Use Unicode regex where available, so non ASCII letters are still detected.

### Update

[Test cases](http://ideone.com/Dg1a8).

#### PHP

```
$testCases = array(
    '',
    'abc',
    '123',
    'لإنجليزية',
    'abc1',
    'русский'
);

foreach($testCases as $str) {
    echo '"' . $str . '" letters only? ' . var_export((bool) preg_match('/^\pL+$/u', $str), TRUE) . "\n";
}
```

#### Output

```
"" letters only? false
"abc" letters only? true
"123" letters only? false
"لإنجليزية" letters only? true
"abc1" letters only? false
"русский" letters only? true
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `preg_match('/^\pL+$/u', $text)`?

Comment: I think this might be dependent on the encoding of the source file. I don't know PHP, though...

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker Well PHP *does* have the `u` modifier, so I don't know. Anyone?

Comment: thanks all but its working only with english alpha but realy my language is arabic can some on help plz

Comment: @user553786 Check update with new test case of an Arabic string that passes.

Comment: @alex really useful stuff!

Comment: it works with all languages .. but it works only incase there is one word (name) .. in order to make it for two words (names) you gotta use this 

`^\pL+\s+\pL+$` --- مصطفى احمد --> true , مصطفى --> false 
Same for other languages ..

Answer (score 2):

A better solution not using regular expression would be to use ctype_alpha

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alpha.php

As long as using the current locale, not just assuming the alphabet is a-zA-Z, is suitable.